# Create FontSizeProperty

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, property-binding

I have a custom control and I want to define a `FontSizeProperty`, which my accessor can use:

```cs
public double FontSize
{
    get
    {
        return (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value);
        this.TextContainer.FontSize = value;
    }
}
```

I've tried a few things, but the app always crashes.

Try 1:

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty FontSizeProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("FontSize", 
                                typeof(double), 
                                typeof(MultiLineButton), 
                                (double)Label.FontSizeProperty.DefaultValue);
```

Exception:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
  at System.Number.ParseDouble (System.String value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo numfmt) [0x00087] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/number.cs:728 
  at System.Double.Parse (System.String s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/double.cs:262 
  at System.Double.Parse (System.String s, System.IFormatProvider provider) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/double.cs:245 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.TypeConversionExtensions.ConvertTo (System.Object value, System.Type toType, System.Func`
1[TResult] getConverter, System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x001f5] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\TypeConversionExtensions.cs:152 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.TypeConversionExtensions.ConvertTo (System.Object value, System.Type toType, System.Func`1[TResult] minfoRetriever, System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x00021] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\TypeConversionExtensions.cs:74 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ValueConverterProvider.Convert (System.Object value, System.Type toType, System.Func`1[TResult] minfoRetriever, System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ValueConverterProvider.cs:15 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Setter.Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IValueProvider.ProvideValue (System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x00062] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Setter.cs:34 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode node, Xamarin.F
orms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x0004d] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ApplyPropertiesVisitor.cs:96 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x000b1] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:175 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00089] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:172 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.FillResourceDictionariesVisitor.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x0017e] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\FillResourceDictionariesVisitor.cs:97 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00008] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:165 
  at Xamarin.For
ms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00089] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:172 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00054] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:223 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode rootnode, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.HydratationContext visitorContext) [0x0006d] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:124 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.String xaml) [0x00046] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:76 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.Type callingType) [0x0002f] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:56 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[TXaml] (
TXaml view, System.Type callingType) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ViewExtensions.cs:36 
  at SomeProject.App.InitializeComponent () [0x00001] in C:\Users\some-user\project\obj\Debug\SomeProject.App.xaml.g.cs:19 
  at SomeProject.App..ctor () [0x00019] in C:\Users\some-user\project\App.xaml.cs:68 
  at SomeProject.iOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication app, Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x000bc] in C:\Users\some-userproject.iOS\AppDelegate.cs:38 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String prin
cipalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
  at SomeProject.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in C:\Users\some-userproject.iOS\Main.cs:17 
2017-07-28 15:04:29.748 SomeProjectiOS[8511:191052] Unhandled managed exception:
Input string was not in a correct format. (System.FormatException)
  at System.Number.ParseDouble (System.String value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo numfmt) [0x00087] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/number.cs:728 
  at System.Double.Parse (System.String s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/double.cs:262 
  at S
ystem.Double.Parse (System.String s, System.IFormatProvider provider) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/double.cs:245 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.TypeConversionExtensions.ConvertTo (System.Object value, System.Type toType, System.Func`1[TResult] getConverter, System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x001f5] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\TypeConversionExtensions.cs:152 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.TypeConversionExtensions.ConvertTo (System.Object value, System.Type toType, System.Func`1[TResult] minfoRetriever, System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x00021] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\TypeConversionExtensions.cs:74 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ValueConverterProvider.Convert (System.Object value, System.Type toType, System.Func`1[TResult] minfoRetriever, System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\Valu
eConverterProvider.cs:15 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Setter.Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IValueProvider.ProvideValue (System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x00062] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Setter.cs:34 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x0004d] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ApplyPropertiesVisitor.cs:96 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x000b1] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:175 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00089] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:172 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.FillResourceDictionariesVisitor.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x0017e] in
 C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\FillResourceDictionariesVisitor.cs:97 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00008] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:165 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00089] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:172 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00054] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:223 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode rootnode, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.HydratationContext visitorContext) [0x0006d] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:124 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.Strin
g xaml) [0x00046] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:76 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.Type callingType) [0x0002f] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:56 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[TXaml] (TXaml view, System.Type callingType) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ViewExtensions.cs:36 
  at SomeProject.App.InitializeComponent () [0x00001] in C:\Users\some-user\project\obj\Debug\SomeProject.App.xaml.g.cs:19 
  at SomeProject.App..ctor () [0x00019] in C:\Users\some-user\project\App.xaml.cs:68 
  at SomeProject.iOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication app, Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x000bc] in C:\Users\some-userproject.iOS\AppDelegate.cs:38 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UI
ApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/d2270eec/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
  at SomeProject.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in C:\Users\some-userproject.iOS\Main.cs:17
```

Try 2:

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty FontSizeProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("FontSize", 
                                typeof(double), 
                                typeof(MultiLineButton), 
                                Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label)));
```

Exception:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Try 3:

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty FontSizeProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("FontSize", 
                                typeof(double), 
                                typeof(MultiLineButton), 
                                null);
```

Exception:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SomeProject.Views.MultiLineButton' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: Not a valid default value
Parameter name: defaultValue
```

What should I use as default value for my `FontSizeProperty`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all your missing is the default number for your font size for example 12d. You'll probably need to explicitly add the d to the number or it may think it is an int at runtime instead of a double.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty FontSizeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(FontSize), typeof(double), typeof(MultiLineButton), 12d);

[TypeConverter(typeof(FontSizeConverter))]
public double FontSize
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: *Unhandled Exception:
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.*

Comment: Makes sure in xaml or wherever you are setting the FontSize you don't have `FontSize="Small"`, `FontSize="Medium"`, or `FontSize="Large"` on your control because that is what will give you the Input string was not in a correct format exception.

Comment: With `<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>` the app doesn't crash anymore. Now also my other approaches seem to work. I saw there is a [`FontSizeConverter`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.FontSizeConverter/) in `Xamarin.Forms`. How could I use this? You could add your comment to your answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: `FontSizeConverter` is pretty much a class you could use to extend and write your own class and override methods like `ConvertFromInvariantString`, `CanConvertFrom`, and `ConvertFrom`. I don't see a reason to really do that unless you wanted another font string like `FontSize="ExtraLarge"` or something like that.

Comment: No, I don't want to overwrite it. I want to be able to use strings e.g. `<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Medium"/>` for my accessor/property.

Comment: To use the built in one on a property there is a xamarin post about it https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/53373/how-labels-fontsize-property-can-accept-integer-and-namedsize-values-in-the-same-time-in-xaml

Comment: Yes, I also found [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37325/how-to-create-a-size-property-for-a-custom-control-that-is-configurable-in-xaml). Perhaps you extend your answer so I could remove mine.

Comment: I extended my answer feel free to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try 12 as the default or what ever number you want. You can always set it to something else when you instantiate the control.

Comment: For `public static readonly BindableProperty FontSizeProperty = BindableProperty.Create("FontSize", typeof(double), typeof(MultiLineButton), 12);` I get "*Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SomeProject.Views.MultiLineButton' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: Default value did not match return type
Parameter name: defaultValue*". Also `public static readonly BindableProperty FontSizeProperty =
   BindableProperty.Create<MultiLineButton, double>(
p => p.FontSize, -1);` is deprecated ...